# Can't pickle StringO objects (while trying to serialize the signature returned from librsync-python module)

Tags: python-2.7, serialization, pickle, librsync

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-librsync/0.1-5

```
import librsync

# The destination file.
dst = file('Resume-v1.0.pdf', 'rb')

# Step 1: prepare signature of the destination file
signature = librsync.signature(dst)
```

I want to store the signature in a file (preferably as a dictionary entry using `pickle`). I would want to calculate the `delta` file afterwards.
How do I save this signature object for future use?

Update:
I tried to pickle the object but it says `TypeError: can't pickle StringO objects`.

Update 2: The signature object that was returned had reference to a file object. Python can't pickle a file object. I solved it using `dill` which is an extended version of the `pickle` module. 
Added it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

I'm the author of the question and this is the solution that worked for me.

From http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-pypers/

> Python cannot pickle a file object (or any object with a reference to
>   a file object), because Python cannot guarantee that it can recreate
>   the state of the file upon unpickling.

From https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dill

> Dill extends python’s ‘pickle’ module for serializing and
>   de-serializing python objects to the majority of the built-in python
>   types.

Using `dill`, I could serialize the signature object that was returned.
https://github.com/uqfoundation/dill

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to pickle the StringIO object, but rather the value of the signature. You need to get the contents of the object:

```
signature_bytes = librsync.signature(dst).getvalue()
pickle(dict(sig=signature_bytes))
```

Comment: Thanks, do you know of any resource where I can get a list of all the methods available in the `librsync` module without going through the source code? I couldn't find any proper documentation.

Comment: StringIO isn't a librsync object, it's a built-in Python object. Docs for the Python module are here: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-librsync/0.1-5

Comment: No `getvalue` method found! `AttributeError: SpooledTemporaryFile instance has no attribute 'getvalue'`

Comment: The error message says `StringO` and not `StringIO`. Maybe they are different?

Comment: The only mention on the web of a `StringO` type is in this page. python-librsync seems to call `tempfile.SpooledTemporaryFile` which says it gives either a `StringIO` or a real file... Either way, pickling it is an over-complicated way to store a string value.